# Convert WSDL to C# classes

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I have problem with integration with my courier (www.raben.com).
I've got WSDL schema http://integrator.raben-group.com/pl/?soap=itginterface.wsdl

I'm using VS2012 .NET 4.0, project type is Class Library used in bigger Solution.
I've added References > Add Service Reference -> http://integrator.raben-group.com/pl/?soap=itginterface.wsdl > Go > Ok

VS add new sys folder Service Refences and put my new "IntegratorRabenServiceReference"

I created XML with XDocument and how can i sent i to them?

Edited:

```
Sample XML data http://jelux.pl/Integrator/sample_data.xml
XSD file http://jelux.pl/Integrator/transport-order-information.xsd
and instruction to XML file http://jelux.pl/Integrator/Import.pdf
```

Comment: What XML file did you create?

Comment: In the defense of @Adrian, that WSDL is crap. Instead of specifying the xml for a request it says that it wants a string, but the parameter name is xml-data. I would recommend you to have a look at a different service for a better understanding of WSDL.

Answer (score 3):

In a sense your question is telling us that you don't really know what you are doing. "How do I fix the carburetor on my carrot?". In it's current format it is not really fit, but I'll try to help you anyhow :)

What you have created are proxy classes for using the webservice. You should be able to create something akin to a `IntegratorRabenService` in which you have all the necessary methods. It's a proxy for the webservice if you will.

```
var service = new IntegratorRabenService(); // Using default endpoint
var data = .... // Whatever your method needs
var result = service.ProxyMethodCall(data);
// Do something with result.
```

Hope that helps some :)

If you need a full example I can help you with that as well since the webservice seems to be public, but you need to tell me so :)

Comment: It will probably be called `IntegratorRabenServiceClient` by default.

Comment: Can you provide a full example?
Today I contacted with Raben but their IT guy has no knowledge about .NET Web Services. They said: He gave me all information to communicate.

Comment: @AdrianBotor I will, I just haven't had time yet, alot to do at work. I'll prolly be able to give an example tomorrow.

Comment: @flindeberg In my class IntegratorRabenServiceReference nothing was generated.
http://jelux.pl/Integrator/1.PNG and http://jelux.pl/Integrator/2.PNG

Comment: @flindeberg. In my old school project there was some classes.  jelux.pl/Integrator/3.PNG

Comment: @flindeberg Project Type for this should be 'WFC Library'?

Comment: @flindeberg. Can you create proxy class SvcUtil.exe? I got error.